# How do I rearrange my UITableView with respect to alphabets or with respect to modified date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

- I have two table views displaying the data from a Sqlite database.
- I can modify the content of the 2 tables. One displayed date and data. One displayed data only.
- I.e. I can change date & time,words as well.
- Now I need to arrange the content with respect to date in 1 table, 
  with respect to alphabets in 2nd table.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be storing your data in some data structure (like array, dictionary etc.), once you edit the date and time, Sort your array or dictionary using  sort descriptors and then reload the table

Answer (score 3):

You can use a sortDescriptor to sort the array (or fetchRequest when using Core Data) you're using. If you've setup your tableViews any other way please provide some more information.

Documentation: [SortDescriptors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Concepts/Creating.html)

Once sorted you can reload your tableView: [tableView reloadData];

Comment: Don't you have a local array (the SQLite resultset) for the UITableView that you can sort when changes occured? Otherwise you'll have to execute a new query each time. To refresh the view itself you'll have to do [tableView reloadData];.

Comment: Get All the data in an array.Use SortDescriptors for sorting.